# Control font on Total row of CPQ quote document

Tags: cpq, quote-template

When previewing the line items section of a CPQ quote document, how can I control the font of the totals line (at the bottom of the table)?  I am able to control the line item rows using the Line Column records, but I can't figure out how to set the Totals field - specifically to make it bold.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a Template Content record and then use it in a Template Section record's look up field? You would need to set the type of Content record as "HTML" Refer to below link for more information.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_template_content.htm&type=5

Comment: I am using a content record, of type Line Items, but it doesn't give me any control over the Totals field (which isn't  technically a line item, but does print itself automatically when I include this section and content).   I was able to control the font of the line item prices using Line Column records on the template itself, but I can't see anywhere to control the font of the Totals field at the bottom.   RIght now the lines are in bold face and the totals are in plain face.

Comment: @DanLambeth we can't change default Total row. In your case you need to hide Total row at all (Edit your quote template record and select the Hide Totals field), then create new Template section just below the Line Items section. In that new section create new Template Content of html type with the Total row and style it like you want. I had many similar cases.

Comment: Thanks Roman -- I'll give this a try